# Limiting compilation error to symbols that are not always loaded

Tags: compilation-mode

At one point, in an attempt to make parsing of `*Compilation*` faster, I customized `compilation-error-regexp-alist` to a set of symbols: `'(cargo rustc-colon rustc rustc-refs bash python-tracebacks-and-caml java maven perl weblint scala gradle-kotlin)`

However, `cargo` is not in `compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist` until I load a file that is in `rust-mode`.

If I start a compile with `rust-mode` not loaded, parsing the `*Compilation*` buffer attempts to look up the `cargo` symbol, gets `nil` and then raises an error trying to search for `nil` as a regex.  It in fact does this dozens of times in a few seconds on a typical build, which is quite loud, annoying and effectively locks emacs until it is done having errors.  I think it also prevents if from finding the actual errors in the buffer.

I see where this is happening, and I could patch my local copy of compile.el, which would work until I updated emacs.

I could also add a hook to push the Rust-related tags onto the list after `rust-mode` is loaded.  That should work until I customize the error alist again, at which point I would need to remember to remove them from the saved value if I have loaded `rust-mode`.

Is there a way to do this which does not require hacking the standard modules or remembering to take extra steps when customizing?

I am using GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0, NS appkit-2022.60 Version 11.6.4 (Build 20G417)) of 2022-03-02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should report this as a bug. It should just silently skip anything that it cannot find in the alist-alist, or maybe issue a warning once. You can run `M-x report-emacs-bug` to send an email to the mailing list.